# Why does NFKC normalization lose superscript & subscript info?

Tags: unicode, text-normalization

I notice that when normalizing a Unicode string to NFKC form, superscript characters like `¹` (U+00B9), `²` (U+00B2), `³` (U+00B3), etc are converted to the corresponding ASCII digit (ex. `1`, `2`, `3`, etc).

Does anyone know the rationale for this behavior?  It seems like it's losing information in the process.  For example, a superscript number usually has some contextual meaning.

Comment: The "K" apparently stands for "compatibility" (well... I guess the "C" was already used for "canonical"). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) says: "Compatible sequences may be treated the same way in some applications (such as sorting and indexing), but not in others; and may be substituted for each other in some situations, but not in others."